# LiveSearch Flask and Ajax returns undefined

Tags: python, ajax, sqlite, undefined, livesearch

I wanted to create a LiveSearch in Flask. So I tried it. I build up a connection to my sqlite Database. In the Database I have only four entries for testing. If I start flask and write into the Inputfield for example "P", I only recieve 4x an "[Undefinded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOhDt.jpg)" as a result, not the wished [entrys from the database like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXoEN.jpg) "PET", "PA6", "PE-LT" and so on. I'm sitting for hours and tried and searched everywhere and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Hope you can help me...

These are my codes I'm using:
`search.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import sqlite3 as sql


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/livesearch", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def livesearch():
    searchbox = request.form.get("text")
    con = sql.connect("DIMOP.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT Kennwert FROM Materialien WHERE Kennwert LIKE ?""", ('%'+searchbox+'%', ))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return jsonify(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="livebox">
<p id="datalist"></p>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#livebox").on("input",function(e){
            textinlivebox = $("#livebox").val();
            $.ajax({
                method:"post",
                url:"/livesearch",
                data:{text:textinlivebox},
                success:function(res){
                    var data = "<ul>";
                    $.each(res,function(index,value){
                        data += "<li>"+value.Kennwert+"</li>";
                    });
                    data += "</ul>";
                    $("#datalist").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Mine is doing the same and the answer below doesn’t help.

Comment: Solution is actually just return value not value.Kennwert

Answer (score 1):

i used something similar to this in one of my projects and it works fine.

views.py:

```
@api.route("/livesearch",methods=["POST"])
def livesearch():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    data = {"name": name}
    return jsonify(data)
```

index.html: without form, just an input.

```
... 
<input type="text" id="livebox" class="form-control text-right">
...
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#livebox").on("input",function(e){
            if($("#livebox").val().length > 4)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    method:"post",
                    url:"/api/livesearch",
                    data:{name:$("#livebox").val()},
                    success:function(res){
                        if(res != '')
                        {
                            console.log(res['name']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('failed');
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

my real **view.py** is this, sorry about my dirty code, im a newbie.

```
@app.route("/livesearch",methods=["POST"])
def livesearch():
    searchbox = request.form.get("text")
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    query = "select * from books where name LIKE '%{}%' order by name".format(searchbox)
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    data = []
    for row in result:
        if row[2] == 'None':
            data.append({'id': row[0], 'name': row[1], 'price':row[4], 'specialprice':row[3], 'img':row[5]})
        else:
            data.append({'id': row[0], 'name': row[1], 'price':row[2], 'specialprice':'0','img':row[5]})
    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: Errors with api not defined